# How to use tetgen's "-i" command in my own project?

Tags: c++, tetgen

### known:

- -i command is used to insert point set(with .node) into a hull(maybe plc,maybe .stl file)

  In the official documentation：

  The -i switch indicates that a list of additional points is going to be inserted
  into an existing tetrahedral mesh. The list of additional nodes is read from
  files xxx.a.node, where xxx stands for the input file name (i.e., xxx.poly or
  xxx.smesh, or xxx.ele, ...).
- I've done inserting points in bounding box and generating CDT with tetgen.exe and tetview.exe.

  Enter in cmd：

> ```
> tetgen -i Stanford_Bunny.stl
> ```

[image]

### problem:

However, I am getting an error when using tetgen's -i command in my own project. Commands such as -p can be used.

```
tetgenio in, out, addin,bgmin;
    in.firstnumber = 0;

    char* infile = new char[100];
    strcpy_s(infile, 100, "C:/delaunay3/data/source/Stanford_Bunny");//use strcpy_s 
    in.load_stl(infile);

    char* add_nodefile = new char[1024];
    strcpy_s(add_nodefile, 100, "C:/delaunay3/data/source/Stanford_Bunny.a");
    addin.load_node(add_nodefile);

    tetgenbehavior* b = new tetgenbehavior();
    b->plc = 1;
    b->quality = 0;             //-q
    b->fixedvolume = 0;         //-a
    b->regionattrib = 0;        //-A
    b->edgesout = 1;            //-e(all edge)
    b->facesout = 0;            //-f(all face)
    b->insertaddpoints = 1;     //-i

    tetrahedralize(b, &in, &out, &addin);

    char* s_nodefile = new char[100];
    char* s_edgefile = new char[100];
    char* s_elefile = new char[100];
    char* s_facefile = new char[100];
    strcpy_s(s_nodefile, 100, "C:/delaunay3/data/s_example");//use strcpy_s
    strcpy_s(s_edgefile, 100, "C:/delaunay3/data/s_exampl");
    strcpy_s(s_elefile, 100, "C:/delaunay3/data/s_example");
    strcpy_s(s_facefile, 100, "C:/delaunay3/data/s_example");
    out.save_nodes(s_nodefile);
    out.save_edges(s_edgefile);
    out.save_elements(s_elefile);
    out.save_faces(s_facefile);

    cout << "plc = " << b->plc<<endl;
    cout << "quality = " << b->quality << endl;
    cout << "edgesout = " << b->edgesout << endl;
    cout << "insertaddpoints = " << b->insertaddpoints << endl;
```

### result:

> Exception thrown at 0x7A0DBCFD (ucrtbased.dll) (in delaunay3.exe):
> 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading location 0xDDDDDDD4.

[image]
[image]

[image]

I used four parameters in`tetrahedralize(b, &in, &out, &addin);`, I don't know if this is the cause.The program can be run by calling -p with three arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a simple solution: **call the console interface directly**

1. firstly, add this in tetgen.h

```cpp
int tetgen(int argc, char* argv[]); //
```

2. secondly, use `not TETLIBRARY` way in tetgen.cxx

```cpp
int tetgen(int argc, char* argv[])  //change this and others place
//int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

3. thirdly

```cpp
char* cmd = (char*)"-i";
char* file_name = (char*)"./example.poly";  //with example.a.node in the same file
void tetgen_methord(char* cmd, char* file_name)     
{
    char* all[3] = { (char*)"tetgen", cmd, file_name };
    tetgen(3, all);
}
```

it's funny but efficient